# getting prolog not to repeat answers

Tags: prolog

```
bigger(whale,shark).
bigger(shark,tiger).
bigger(tiger,dog).
bigger(dog,rat).
bigger(rat,ant).
bigger(rat,mouse).
bigger(cat,rat).
bigger(dog,cat).

smaller(X,Y) :- bigger(Y,X).
smaller(X,Y) :- bigger(Z,X),smaller(Z,Y).
```

When I ask prolog `smaller(X,whale)` it spits out all the correct animals but repeats several of them. can anyone tell me why and if there's a way to stop it repeating?

Answer (score 2):

Some remarks first:

What kind of relation does the predicate `bigger/2` describe, really?

- Because of the name, we assume it is *transitive*: `bigger(A, B)` *and* `bigger(B, C)` ==> `bigger(A, C)`
- We also can safely assume it is *strict* (and not *reflexive*): `bigger(A, A)` can never be true
- And *assymetric* (not *symmetric*): `bigger(A, B)` ==> `bigger(B, A)` is not true
- What we **cannot** know from the program as it stands, is if the relation describes either a *total ordering*, or a *weak ordering*: we don't know whether (a) `bigger(mouse, ant)`, or (b) *not* `bigger(mouse, ant)`, or (c) `mouse` and `ant` are equivalent (we assume they are definitely not *equal*)

All this just to say that you don't have a *linear ordering* for all the elements for which the `bigger` relation is defined. If you did, you could sort all animals (say bigger to smaller) and do something like:

```
animal_bigger(A, Bigger) :-
    animal_list(Animals),
    append(Bigger, [A|_Smaller], Animals),
    member(A, Bigger).
```

Since you **do not have a linear ordering**, it is not possible to sort all elements and simplify the questions "what is smaller/bigger" to "what comes before/after". Instead, we need to *traverse the graph* described by `bigger/2`. At least we can safely assume that it is a *directed*, *acyclic* graph. I leave it as an exercise how to traverse a graph. To solve this problem, we can instead use [`library(ugraphs)`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=ugraphs) (you can see the source [here](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/swi/library/ugraphs.pl?show=src)), and to answer, "which animals are smaller than X", we can instead ask, "which nodes are reachable from X":

Here is the complete program:

```
bigger(whale,shark).
bigger(shark,tiger).
bigger(tiger,dog).
bigger(dog,rat).
bigger(rat,ant).
bigger(rat,mouse).
bigger(cat,rat).
bigger(dog,cat).

:- use_module(library(ugraphs)).

animal_graph(G) :-
    findall(A-B, bigger(A, B), Edges),
    vertices_edges_to_ugraph([], Edges, G).

animal_smaller(A, B) :-
    animal_graph(G),
    reachable(A, G, R),
    select(A, R, Smaller),
    member(B, Smaller).
```

You can transpose the graph and look for reachable nodes if you want to find all elements that are bigger instead.

I hope you take the time to read this answer...

**EDIT**

At the end, the message is:

Your `bigger/2` does not describe a list (it is not a linear ordering), and it does not describe a tree (you have more than one path to the same node). So, an algorithm that would work on a list does not work here, and an algorithm that would work on a tree does not work, either. So you either have to implement your `smaller/2` to work with a graph, or use a library that can deal with graphs.

Comment: Boris thanks and I will definitely read and try to understand what you have said. It is blowing my mind a little though currently. I am very grateful.

Comment: @neilsouthin The whole point is that unless you understand _why_ you get the same answer more than once, you can't start deciding how to avoid it.

Comment: I can see that - and that is exactly what i'm trying to do - thanks again Boris!

Answer (score 1):

#### Using library solution_sequences

In recent versions of the SWI-Prolog development branch this has been made particularly easy:

```
?- use_module(library(solution_sequences)).
true.
?- distinct(X, smaller(X, whale)).
X = shark ;
X = tiger ;
X = dog ;
X = rat ;
X = ant ;
X = mouse ;
X = cat ;
false.
```

The library that allows this is documented [over here](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=solutionsequences).

#### Using library aggregate

Another way in which this can be done (also supported in older versions of SWI-Prolog):

```
?- aggregate_all(set(X), smaller(X, whale), Xs), member(X, Xs).
```

Comment: thanks - the version i'm using doesn't seem to like the use_module line.

Comment: @neilsouthin Then you're either not using SWI-Prolog or you do not have a recent enough version. Info on installing recent/developer releases can be found [over here](http://www.swi-prolog.org/download/devel). There are other ways in which you can enforce unique results though, I'll add one of them to my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

a possible standard Prolog usage:

```
?- X=whale,setof(Y,smaller(Y,X),L).
X = whale,
L = [ant, cat, dog, mouse, rat, shark, tiger].
```

I've attempted to evidence the 'functional dependencies' with the choice of symbols. When you have a list, you can use member/2 to enumerate elements.